# How to switch off devices and ports for power saving in Lubuntu?

Tags: power-management

In Windows Vista I can switch off via power management:
PCI Express
Modem port
Optical DVD drive

Via network connection I disable:
Blutooth

How can I do similar in Lubuntu? Under Power Manager I don't have the options.

It would be good to have a GUI manager for this.

Comment: there is no gui tools ...for power management

Comment: But my question title is better for noobs :P ?

Answer (score 0):

[**Improve Power Usage / Battery Life In Linux With TLP**](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/improve-power-usage-battery-life-in.html), I been using TLP from 3 to 4 weeks and My laptop is running 4 to 5 Deg cooler than windows 7/8, so here the tlp installation and configuration

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install tlp tlp-rdw smartmontools ethtool
```

**Configuration**

```
 sudo update-rc.d -f ondemand remove
```

The main config file of TLP is at /etc/default/tlp

```
  sudo gedit /etc/default/tlp
```

Go to **cpu frequency** Section and and uncomment the following lines add the following config.

```
CPU_SCALING_GOVERNOR_ON_AC=conservative
CPU_SCALING_GOVERNOR_ON_BAT=conservative
```

Next Section **Set the cpu "turbo boost"**, uncomment if commented

```
 CPU_BOOST_ON_AC=1
 CPU_BOOST_ON_BAT=0
```

Next Section **Radeon graphics clock speed**, comment it if you not using **Radeon graphics**

```
 #RADEON_POWER_PROFILE_ON_AC=high
 #RADEON_POWER_PROFILE_ON_BAT=low
```

Next Section **optical drive**

```
 BAY_POWEROFF_ON_BAT=1
```

Next Section **PM for *all* pci(e) bus devices**, Warning: experimental option, could cause system instabilities..But i found no problem just you have to put usb 2 devices in usb 2 port and usb 3 devices in usb 3 port

```
 RUNTIME_PM_ALL=1
```

Some times my usb mouse dongle didn't work when i plug it in usb 3 port, work fine when i plug it in usb 2 port, and all my usb 3 devices are working properly no issue.

**Save & Exit**

You can also configure Devices to Disable on startup etc, there is very good help in config file.

I have an error that my **Blue tooth** device is not Disabled on start up, so if you face this problem just do the following config

```
 sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

And add the following line before exit 0

```
 rfkill block bluetooth
```

**Save & Exit & Reboot**

**Optional**

Install indicator-cpufreq that help you alot Changing freq

```
 sudo apt-get install indicator-cpufreq
```

Go to Dash > search startup > edit indicator-cpufreq add -f or copy paste the following command

```
 indicator-cpufreq -f
```

[image]

[image]

this will let you see what **Freq** you are running.

**Done**

**Optional**

**[PowerSavingTweaks](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/PowerManagement/PowerSavingTweaks)** Intel Graphics

```
 sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

change:

```
 GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to:

```
 GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i915.lvds_downclock=1 drm.vblankoffdelay=1"
```

and run:

```
 sudo update-grub
```

**Done Reboot**

You do not need other tweaks as they are already added by defaults.

Check you TLP Stat

```
 sudo tlp-stat
```

Check You System temperature

```
 sudo tlp-stat -t
```

[There is very good help at TLP Website](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-linux-advanced-power-management.html)

[Useful Config Link 1](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-faq.html)

[TLP Settings](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-configuration.html)